# Computing $\gcd$ of very large numbers with powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to calculate $\gcd$ of $5^{2^{303} - 1} - 1$ and $5^{2^{309} - 1} - 1$?

I stumbled upon this interesting problem and tried elementary algebraic simplification and manipulation. But found no success.

Comment: Why would that be an interesting problem?

Comment: I think it's interesting because of its solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$gcd(5^a - 1,5^b -1) = 5^{gcd(a,b)} -1$$

Comment: =5^(gcd(a,b)) - 1 or 5 * (gcd(a,b)) - 1 ?

Comment: @John $5^{gcd(a,b)} -1$